# Substring from specific position

Tags: php, string

I have a problem to find closest tag open `<` from the specific position in a string.

In content string(big one) I find the position of the desired word.

`$keyword_position = stripos($content, $keyword);`

then I need from that position to find closest `<` tag open so result won't break tags like `<img src='http://blablala.com/img/test.png` if `keyword` was test. Or avoid breaking paragraph or so.

Thanks

Comment: The next `<` tag? or the closest `<` tag?

Comment: Get the positions of < all in array and compare with the keyword position. Just took the nearest one from that array and so on.

Comment: Closest previous `<`.

Comment: You can now use substr with the nearest one and keyword position so you get the substring.

Comment: Is the content HTML? Does it have to be a `<` which opens a tag? What about the `<` in the middle of `<!--this < is in a comment-->`, or the less-than operator in `<script> if (foo < bar) { ... } </script>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this code:

```
$keyword_position = stripos($content, $keyword);
$content_substring=substr($content,0,strlen($content)-$keyword_position);
$goal_position=strrpos($content_substring ,"<");
```

strrpos get last index of keyword.
other php functions used are clear. :)